# Method "Insert" of Object "Range" Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I created this sub for add information in a table when an img is pressed, sometimes working but sometimes give me the error, in this line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert`, what will be the problem?

```
 Private Sub imgGenerarCargoAceptar_Hover_click()

   If txtCuentas_Fecha = "" Or cmbCuentas_Clientes = "" Or txtCuentas_Espacio = "" _
   Or txtCuentas_Cuota = "" Or txtCuentas_Concepto = "" Then
    MsgBox "Por favor rellenar todos los datos.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Control Book"
        Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("A2").Value = Me.txtCuentas_Fecha
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("B2").Value = Me.cmbCuentas_Clientes
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("C2").Value = Me.txtCuentas_Espacio
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("D2").Value = Format(Me.txtCuentas_Cuota, "\$#,##0.00")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cuentas").Range("E2").Value = Me.txtCuentas_Concepto
        MsgBox "La factura se ha generado con exito.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Control Book"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error number and message you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the parameters of the *Insert* arguments,  e.g. `.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow`? If the table is an Excel table (*ListObject*), you should reference it and use its methods and properties.

Comment: **'Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'Insert' of object 'Ranged' failed**
Im getting this message

Comment: Ok, i got the answer by myself, if someone more have this same problem, just need to change the range, i just put A3 and its work!